# Get Characters From String in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Please, could someone help me how to display only the content of the brackets(bbbb)?
The following code shows the content outside of the brackets and I can not figure it out...

```
    dim strText, remove
strText = "aaaa(bbbb)cccc"

Dim str1, str2

str1 = InStr(strText, "(") 
Do While str1 > 0 
    str2 = InStr(str1 + 1, strText, ")") 
    If str2 > 0 Then 
        strText = Left(strText, str1 - 1) & Mid(strText, str2 + 1) 
    Else 
        Exit Do 
    End If 
    str1 = InStr(strText, "(") 
Loop 

remove = strText 
response.write(remove)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strYouAreLookingFor = mid(strText, InStr(strText, "("), (InStrRev(strText, ")") - InStr(strText, "(") + 1) )
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about using this string to do what I needed, and it worked out perfectly. Thanks.